# How can I approximate this characteristic function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, approximation

> Let $F\subset \Bbb{R}^d$ be a closed subset. Let us define $f(x)=\Bbb{1}_F(x)$. I want to approximate this function by a continuous function.

If $d=1$ I know how to solve this problem, but if $d$ is arbitrary I have some problems.
In internet I found someone who defined $f_m(x)=\max\{0,1-m\cdot d(x,F)\}$ and claimed that $f_m$ approximates $f$. The problem is that I don't see how it works. Is there some intuition behind this?

It would be nice if someone could explain me the inuition.

Comment: In large abstraction, Urysohn's Lemma. You can in fact choose smooth approximations, which you might find with searches for partitions of unity on manifolds. The example $f_m(x)$ works (but isn't smooth). Which part of $f_m$ as an approximation don't you like? You can check that $f_m(x) = 1$ for all $x \in F$, and $f_m(x) = 0$ for all $x$ at least $1/m$ away from $F$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Yes I see that $f_m$ satisfies your two properties but I would not have come up with this idea since the intuition is missing somehow

Comment: One way to build a smooth approximation is to first construct a limited support function $\phi(x)$ where $x\in \mathbb R^n$ such that A) $\int_{R^n} \phi(x) dx = 1$ and B) $\forall |x|>\epsilon: \phi(x)=0$.  Convolution of $1_{F(x)}$ and $\phi$ will be a pretty good approximation which is as smooth as $\phi$.  To construct $\phi$ one can use splines. The higher the order of the splines the smoother the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe look at it from this point of view: The distance function $x\longmapsto d(x,F)$ is intuitively useful when it comes to encoding information about a set $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

For the characteristic function $f = 1_F$, one has $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in F$, while $d(x,F)=0$ for all $x\in F$... so naturally,  $1-d(x,F)$ looks promising, since one has $f(x) = 1-d(x,F)$ for all $x\in F$.

However, one would also like to emulate the property $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin F$, which is not given by $1-d(x,F)$, since this function can become arbitrarily negative if one moves far enough away from $F$.

So in order to not get below zero, one instead looks at $\max\{0,1-d(x,F)\}$. Now, this function is the same as $f$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that either lie in $F$, or lie in $F^c$ and have distance $d(x,F)\geq 1$.

This means that we have to look at a sequence of continuous functions $$f_m := \max\{0,1-m d(x,f)\}$$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$, since they coincide with $f$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that either lie in $F$, or lie in $F^c$ and have distance $d(x,F)\geq\frac{1}{m}$. So $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise against $f$, since for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a $M\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $f(x) = f_m(x)$ for all $m\geq M$.

Comment: Perfect thanks!